# MySQL query to find the latest record of each hour slot for a date

Tags: mysql

We have an **event** mysql table where we store the events generated from different kind of sensors. Below is the create table query for the same table.

```
CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `device_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `device_type` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `data` text NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_event_device_idx` (`device_id`),
  KEY `event_device_type` (`device_type`),
  KEY `event_created_at_idx` (`created_at`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_event_device` FOREIGN KEY (`device_id`) REFERENCES `device` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

We have a foreign key of device_id from device table and device table has a foreign key of zone_id from zone table.

Given a date, we want to find the latest events of devices(of same device_type) of a zone for each hour slot. Ex: Let's say there are 4 events generated between 4:00PM to 5:00PM by one device, latest event is the one which was sent last in that hour slot. So, the input is *zone_id*, *device_type* & *date* and the output should be something like below:

```
Devices | 00:00 to 01:00 | 01:00 to 02:00 | 02:00 to 03:00 | 03:00 to 04:00 | 04:00 to 05:00 | ... | 23:00 to 24:00
```

What should be the performant query to do the same?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

In fresh version of MySQL you can use window functions. Somthing like this.

```
SELECT
LAST_VALUE(e1.id) OVER (PARTITION BY e1.id ORDER BY e1.created_at),
FROM event e1
GROUP BY DAY(e1.created_at), HOUR(e1.created_at);
```

Comment: Can you please explain the query you have mentioned above? The query is giving me below syntax error:

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY e1.id ORDER BY e1.created_at) FROM event e1 GROUP BY DAY(e1.create' at line 1`

Comment: Unfortunately this syntax works with MySQL 8+ (current version is RC) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html